# How to configure number of child-processes in Play webapp

Tags: playframework

I hava (multiple) play apps running (Play Framework 2.5). The process list with "htop" looks like that:

```
  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
    1            20   0 33520  2524  1400 S  0.0  0.0  0:39.75 /sbin/init
29166            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.6  1.6  0:59.18 ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Ddatab
32625            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.15 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
32624            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.13 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
31932            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.21 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
31931            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.22 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
31929            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.19 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
31722            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.24 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
31530            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.23 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
30702            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.28 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
30684            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.36 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
30666            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.42 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
30406            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.37 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
30387            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.00 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
30382            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.6  1.6  0:17.01 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
30354            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:01.19 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
30280            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:17.17 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29764            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.00 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29668            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:03.50 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29667            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.00 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29666            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:01.95 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29665            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:04.78 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29664            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:04.20 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29663            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.00 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29656            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.01 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29654            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.01 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29642            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.45 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29639            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.10 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29637            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.10 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29635            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.09 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29634            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.09 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29631            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.09 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29630            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.10 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
29629            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:05.12 │  ├─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
  696            20   0 3685M  191M 12700 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.11 │  └─ java -Duser.dir=/var/www/K3655579/myapp.mydomain.ch/playapps/myapp -Dmyapp.name=myapp -Dmyapp.features=myapp -Dda
```

As you can see, this one web app starts 33 child processes, which eat a lot of memory. Where can I configure Play to use only like 5 child processes (since there is not much traffic on the website/webapp, this should be enough).

Thank you,
schube

Comment: Those should be threads, not processes. Use `ps xau | grep 'myapp.name=myapp'` and see if you get the same numbers

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Your command returns 1 line, so this is one process, okay. I was confused because htop shows 191MB per thread, but I guess this counts for the whole process. (Background is, I have 12GB of RAM and my app should use only 8GB (43 instances with 190MB each). But instead of 4GB free space (minus some other OS related things) i have like 100KB free mem and heavy swap usage.) But it seems like I have to look somewhere else. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Htop by default shows each thread as a separate process. Maybe this can help you.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/why-does-htop-show-more-process-than-ps